# Extension of lower end of the vocal range

Tags: voice, vocal-range, vocal-cords, bass-voice

I'm a 17 year old male with a comfortable range of D2- E2-E4-F#4
I've been working on my lower as well as the higher end of my vocal range and while I've gotten better at the highest end, just recently getting past E4 without straining, my lows seem unaffected and I can't seem to get any lower than that D2 (except, of course, in the mornings, when I can get down to an A#1 on good days and B1 on a daily basis, but they don't count).

So I don't really know if I'm gonna be stuck at this D2 forever or if there are hopes for me to get to a good C2 or even, hopefully, a B1 as I get older.

Comment: What's the difference between A#1 and Bb1, especially since you say that "I can get down to an A#1 on good days and Bb1 on a daily basis" in the morning? Is A#1 very slightly lower than Bb1 or what?

Comment: Oh wow. Yeah no I just got my notes mixed up, sorry about that. I meant a B1 not Bb1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend Lower Vocal Range](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/80662/extend-lower-vocal-range)

Answer (score 1):

this is fun to say, but here's what happened to me.

I practiced my low range for about a year and nothing changed.

Then, this year during winter break, aàI cought a bad cold and couldn't speak for a few days.

Since then I can get almost a tone under. (I couldn't go any lower than F, and now I'm almost at Eb).

So I think if you practice, it pobably won't change until you get something stopping you from speaking form a few days.

So good luck.

Btw, if you can already go down to D2, should be enough for almost all, no?

Comment: However, while I'm not exactly saying a D2 isn't enough, there are a few songs that I really want to sing that go down to a C2 or C#2 at some parts and it's really off putting when I can't hit it without frying or not hitting it at all. I know I can sing different songs but I'm kinda stubborn about it.