# Does one's voice get lower with age?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, voice-training, vocal-cords, bass-voice

Does your voice (range) get lower as you age?
Is this a fact?
If so, does it affect your lower as well as the higher end of the vocal range ( the lower end expands a small bit and some of the upper end notes get harder to hit)?
Is this good for bass singers?

Comment: I'm not an expert, just 45, but I have not noticed any positive effects of aging on my voice. Both my lower and upper ends of my range have constricted a bit, although that might not exactly be aging as much as not having the stamina to keep my voice in shape and finding it harder and harder every year to stay hydrated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Todd! I forgot to mention that I'm talking about the effects of age on the voice of someone who practices regularly. I'll edit that later! I'm guessing it's different for everyone though as I've heard others being able to go even higher or lower than they could a decade before!

Comment: Yes, but you lose far more off the top than you gain at the bottom. Related: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/80662/extend-lower-vocal-range

Answer (score 1):

As a VERY general rule, yes, you'll lose some top range. It would be most unusual for age to bring an EXTENDED high range!   I make no further predictions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now 60 and sing often.  My voice has not lowered but I have lost some of the power of my top range.  I compensate for this by singing more softly at the very top of my range. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

One effect of aging is a loss of muscle mass.  Since the vocal folds have muscle in them, this can lead to a loss of lower range because a less massive oscillator will oscillate more rapidly.  I began to notice this in my early 30s.  I did get a slight improvement in my upper range along with it.  Practicing, like any exercise, tends to build muscle mass, so reduces the severity of this effect.

Ossification of cartilage and loss of flexibility and elasticity generally also tend to have negative effects on vocal timbre and range, on both ends.  Again, practice helps to mitigate these effects.