# Will my vocal range become lower as I get older?

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I’m a 14 year old male right now and the lowest note I can hit is D#2; my highest note is C4 (on a good day). Can I expect my range to become lower than it already is as I get older, or will my range stay about what it is now?

Btw I’m untrained if that has any factor.

Comment: I imagine that at age 14, your voice will change over time for certain. Particularly that C4 as the highest note. Do you know what falsetto is, or if you can use it? Are you certain that that's the correct octave? Because right now, as this question is written, *you seem* to have a pretty low bass voice, but of course I advise that you seek professional vocal instruction for a real answer to this question. There are too many unknowns to really answer this kind of question. From the range you gave, I'm assuming that you're male; if you're not, that would change the question drastically.

Comment: I don't believe this is an answerable question. It's like saying I'm 14, 5'7", how tall will I end up? At 14, you *may* have reached the llmits - or they will change for the next good few years. And in any case, what difference will it make if there *was* an accurate answer - which there isn't! Sorry.

Comment: Please check the helpcenter before asking questions. This might be a duplicate-question. Possible duplicate of [Does one's voice get lower with age?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/81450/does-ones-voice-get-lower-with-age)

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot and yes I know what a falsetto voice is but I can’t use it

Comment: Unless I’m using it without knowing

Answer (score 5):

Short Answer: Yes, it will get lower.

Longer Answer: You should know first that your voice won’t fully mature until you are in your 30’s. Even after you finish adolescence, your voice will continue to change and mature throughout your 20’s and into your 30’s, and these changes are especially noticeable if you have regular vocal training. This happens to both men and women and is completely normal.

Men’s and women’s voices both get lower when they age. As the saying goes, “everything sags”. Skin looses elasticity, and like skin, the vocal folds loose their natural firmness and relax with age. Just look at many popular singers: Billy Joel plays just about everything several keys lower than when he originally wrote them, Elton John too, remarking that his old recordings sound like “he’s on helium”, and Steven Tyler, who no longer emits feral screeches as he did in the 70’s.

That said, there are a couple contributing factors, both good and bad:

1. Smoking will damage your voice and will degrade it faster over time.
2. Screaming / straining / whispering will also hurt your voice.
3. Taking vocal lessons and / or singing with good technique will help you retain your voice well into old age.